# Is My Income from Freelancing Work Halal?

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, work

**As-salamu alaykum,**

When I was 14-years old I wanted to do freelancing work related to programming and web development as I was very interested in that field. I opened up an account on [Upwork.com](http://www.upwork.com) (then oDesk). However, I didn't know that in [Upwork Terms of Service](https://www.upwork.com/legal/) they state that in order to open an account on Upwork one must be at least 18-years old. I open up an account without knowing this information. I honestly didn't even know you're supposed to read their Terms of Service before opening an account.

Then I worked on a number of different projects and earned quite a lot of money. Now I must mention that I was only paid by my clients to work on their web development projects and the projects themselves were not haram. I created applications and those applications didn't have any haram use or didn't contain anything contrary to the Sharia.

I recently realized this and I understood that I made a big mistake. I regretted this decision and repented to Allah. But currently, I really need this money. Now my question is, is the income I earned from freelancing be considered halal?

***In short***, I unknowingly opened up an account but the work I did was halal, so will the income be halal too?

Thank you very much for your answers,

Abraar

Comment: May Allah increase us in the knowledge of His deen. And make Halal and Haraam clear to us all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Walaikum salammm warahmatullahi wabarakatuh,

Yes In Shaa Allah your income is halal. And you can use that money. And you should contact them and explain to them what happened and ask them if they would allow you to work on there website even though you don't  fulfill the requirement of there policy.

And Allah knows best